# I want to print the pair of elements of a list starting from 1 index

Tags: python

I have a list containing

```
l = ['in','1out','1in','2out','2in','3out','3in']
```

and i want to pair the list **starting from the index 1** and so on.
I have written as-

```
zip(l[1::2], l[2::1])
```

> It **prints** as-

```
[('1out', 'in'), ('2out', '1in'), ('3out', '2in')]
```

> But I want as-

```
[('1out', '1in'), ('2out', '2in'), ('3out', '3in')]
```

Thanks if anyone could help..

Comment: Your code doesn't print the result you've pasted. But anyways same code does give the desired result with a slight correction. `zip(l[1::2], l[2::2])`

Comment: @umutto Just saw you wrote this when I added it to my answer. I'll remove it, you create an answer with that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it's cool, OP got their answer, you can add this to your answer. Thanks for suggesting though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.  Just need the `l[2::2]` instead of `l[2::1]` for the second argument to the `zip` function.  You need to skip every other value starting with the second.

```
>>> list(zip(l[1::2], l[2::2]))
[('1out', '1in'), ('2out', '2in'), ('3out', '3in')]
```